# Use sudo in combination with libnss_switch

Tags: sudo, docker, passwd

I implemented `libnss_wrapper` in the entrypoint of a docker container, in order to "create" the user passed via `docker run -u UID`.
This script also creates a `/etc/sudoers.d/USER` file to allow sudo access.

When I try to run `sudo`, I get the error `sudo: you do not exist in the passwd database`.

What can I do to tell sudo to use `$NSS_WRAPPER_PASSWD` instead of `/etc/passwd`?

**Edit** As @todd-c-miller pointed out, this is not possible. As he [pointed out](https://github.com/sudo-project/sudo/issues/46#issuecomment-617450457), one can use proper NSS modules like *[nss-altfiles](https://github.com/aperezdc/nss-altfiles) (Fedora, ...)* or *[nss-extrausers](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/libnss-extrausers) (Debian, Ubuntu)* which allow usage if files in alternative locations.

Answer (score 3):

Since nss_wrapper relies on LD_PRELOAD you cannot use it with sudo.  The dynamic linker ignores LD_PRELOAD for set-user-ID executables like sudo (you would have the same issue with something like su).

See the description of "Secure-execution mode" in the ld.so manual for more information.